# Array in php: Adding 1 to elements with limit + increasing the next elements

Tags: php

I want to add +1 to elements of an array. If a limit is reached, the next element of the array is increased. If all of them reached maximum, it stops.

For example, the array has 5 elements, **maximum is 3**, starting all with value 0:

```
$arr = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

- iteration 1 (adding +1): 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
- = maximum is, e.g., 3
- iteration 2 (adding +1): 2, 0, 0, 0, 0
- iteration 3 (adding +1): 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
- = maximum is reached
- iteration 4 (adding +1): 3 (not 4), 1 (because previous has an overflow), 0, 0, 0
- iteration 5 (adding +1): 3, 2, 0, 0, 0
- ...
- iteration n-1 (adding +1): 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
- = maximum reached
- iteration n (adding +1): 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, (1)
- end

Comment: to make it a little bit more specific, the function should work with a variable number of elements - NOT just for 5 elements

Comment: What have you tried, what problems did you run into? Is this about the _process_ (of doing this in iterative steps), or is the end result all that you are interested in? (Because you could _calculate_ the result, rather than assembling it step-by-step.)

Comment: This question is Unclear because we don't know if you want to generate a multidimensional array filled with all of the incrementions or if you only want the end result as a 1-dim array.  We don't see your best coding attempt, so this question has no context.  We don't know if you would be happy to use `array_fill()` with the `$limit` value and count the number of elements in your `$arr`.  Are you limiting the number of iterations too?  This would provide the possibility of non-limited element values.  I am happy to remove my downvote and retract my close vote if you improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does what you have asked, and will work for any number of elements in `$arr` array, you can also set the limit by changing the `$limit` variable.

```
<?php

    //This is your input
    $arr = array(
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        );

    //This is the maximum number
    $limit = 3;

    //This is your iteration
    foreach( $arr as $key=>$value ){        
        while($value < $limit){
            $value++;
            $arr[$key] = $value;
            echo str_replace( "\n", "", print_r($arr, true)) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

?>
```

When I ran this code, I got the following output:

```
Array(    [0] => 1    [1] => 0    [2] => 0    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 2    [1] => 0    [2] => 0    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 0    [2] => 0    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 1    [2] => 0    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 2    [2] => 0    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 0    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 1    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 2    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 0    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 1    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 2    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 3    [4] => 0)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 3    [4] => 1)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 3    [4] => 2)
Array(    [0] => 3    [1] => 3    [2] => 3    [3] => 3    [4] => 3)
```

Which is what you asked for.

If you wish to do something with the output, change the line `echo str_replace( "\n", "", print_r($arr, true)) . PHP_EOL;` to whatever action you want to do.